# OpenTl c# IDialogs doesn't have an extension CS1061

Tags: c#

I want to search all the telegram channels available with this :

```cs
var clientApi = await ClientFactory.BuildClientAsync(settings).ConfigureAwait(true);
IDialogs userDialogs = await clientApi.MessagesService.GetUserDialogsAsync(100).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

and then get the chats, so channels like this :

```cs
var s = userDialogs.Chats.AsEnumerable; //.Chats.asEnumerable();
```

but I can't compile it because it's throwing this error :

```
Error CS1061 'IDialogs' does not contain a definition for 'Chats' and no accessible extension method 'Chats' accepting a first argument of type 'IDialogs' was found (is a using directive or assembly reference missing?).
```

I'm using OpenTl and when I try to debug it, the userDialogs as an attribute Chats, as well as some others.

[OpenTL library](https://github.com/OpenTl/OpenTl.ClientApi)

Comment: What is `Chats`? It seems `IDialogs` doesn't have it. Are you missing a cast?

Comment: What's a cast ? Chats is an enumerable that contains all the chats of the telegram, but I can only see it in the debugger and in the metadata I see in fact that IDialogs doesnt have it, but I dont know how to add it or somehow

Comment: What is the actual **type** of data shown in debugger? You are likely just need to cast to that type: `var s = ((SomeTypeHereWhichHasChatsPublicProperty)userDialog).Chats...`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the solution : `var userDialogs =(TDialogsSlice)(await clientApi.MessagesService.GetUserDialogsAsync(100).ConfigureAwait(true));`